# Pass value to codeigniter and get it

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form I am sending the value a that is 999

```
<script>
    var a = "999";
</script>

<form action="tests/ETray/New/" method="POST">
    <input id="start-test" type="hidden" name="userid" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Go" style="font-size:14px; padding:20px;">
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(event){
        $('#start-test').val(a);
    })
</script>
```

I now want to use that in codeigniter, how do I use this ?

Comment: You can send the value a with the form to the codeigniter

Comment: And where exactly your problem is?

Comment: I am sending the value start_test = a a = 999,

Comment: @Dekel how do i now retrieve the vale sent in codeignighter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter is a PHP framework. You can use the `$_POST` variable or the [`input` class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#class-reference):

```
$_POST['userid'];
// OR
$this->input->post('userid');
```

The `input` class gives you the ability to automatically prevent cross-site scripting attacks.

Comment: Excellent, if i use this in my controller c?an i set $this->input->post('userid'); as a variable and how to send it to a different controller ?

Comment: What do you mean? You can access the value and set to to some other variable if you want.

Comment: Thanks ill try this

Comment: I will do, can i also use $this->input->post('userid'); on a different controller or dose it have to be on New ?

Comment: You can use `this->input->post` on any controller, but **only** if the value was posted to that controller

Comment: ahh ok, thanks anyways. as i now have $this->input->post('userid'); on my main controller how could i pass the value to a different controller ?